# _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["ɵvid"] is not a function

Tags: angular, e2e-testing, cypress

When I run my E2E tests for my Angular 6 application with Cypress the following error rises from time to time:

`_angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["ɵvid"]`

Sometimes I change a single line of code and everything works fine again.
I have no clue why this happens.

As I already found out, `ɵvid` references the `viewDef` function in the compiled output js file. It seems that this function is not defined.

The component that fires the error is defined in a lazy loaded module.
The component should already be loaded at the time the error arises since all views before are already contained in the same module.

Here is my setup in which the error occurs:

- Angular 6.0.9
- Cypress 3.0.1
- BitBucket Pipelines in the Cloud running a container moneymeets/cypress-python (https://hub.docker.com/r/moneymeets/cypress-python/)

If you need more information, please let me know.

I appreciate any advice or ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by [Cypress issue #1396](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1396). You can fix it by setting `modifyObstructiveCode` to `false` in your `cypress.json` config file.